# Sequential Copy and Paste Macro to a reference cell

Tags: excel, vba

I need some help with a macro.

Currently, I have a macro set up that will produce a form based off of a set of data.

The reference value has to be entered one by one to pull the data.

Does anyone know how to have for example

```
A2 = sheet("results").range "C3" 
activecell.offset(0 1).select
Keep going till no value in cell
```

I'm trying to have `A2` contain the value from the other sheet's row 3 (starting at column C), then run the rest of the script and loop back and then have the `A2` value have the next value in line (1st loop would be `C3`, second loop would be `D3`, etc) until the cell on the results sheet is empty?

I'm stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO, Comie B! Suggest you go this way:

Put the list of `reference` values in Sheet2, row 3, starting in column `C`. Have script loop through that row until empty cell is encountered (then `break`). For each iteration, put the current cell value from row 3 into the cell of your "form" (assuming you don't mean a `UserForm` but one in a table grid with cell `A2` being where your want the reference value be placed and the rest of the form being pulled from other sources.

```
Sub Test()
    Dim reference_list As Range
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
        Set reference_list = .Range(.Cells(3, 3), .Cells(3, .UsedRange.Columns.Count))
        For Each reference In reference_list
            If reference.Value = "" Then Exit For
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Value = reference.Value
            ' do whatever you were going to do with the filled out form
            ' ...
        Next reference
    End With
End Sub
```

*Note that Excel sheets are limited to 16k columns, so if you have more reference values than that, you'd have to switch to putting them in a column instead of a row.*